# How would you approach running a containerized application on IPFS

Tags: docker, linux-kernel, cloud, containers, ipfs

I'm wondering if it is possible to run a containerized application, such as a linux-kernel image, over IPFS.

How would the files be executable, and has it been done before?

Comment: What's IPFS?  What kind of containerization system were you thinking of?  (Docker always uses the host's kernel, since you named it in a tag.)

Comment: The Inter-Planetary File System. I'm thinking of a containerized kernel running as a virtual machine on a number of IPFS nodes.